# Android ViewPager crash: InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class

Tags: android, timer, android-viewpager, android-inflate, android-memory

I have created a slideshow using ViewPager, it works ok, but it crashes my app sometimes. There are only 3 pics loaded into it, I use a Timer to make it scroll automatically, onPause I cancel the timer.

I don't really understand why does it crash from time to time, It may be some memory issue? The images are quite small, how could I fix this?

CustomPagerAdapter:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    int[] mResources;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] mResources) {
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mResources = mResources;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        try {
            imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);          
            container.addView(itemView);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }



        return itemView;
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
private CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Timer swipeTimer;
    protected int currentPage;

    int[] mResources = { 
            R.drawable.homeslide1, 
            R.drawable.homeslide3,
            R.drawable.homeslide2
            };

    private Editor editor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

            editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("orderStatus", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();            

            mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getActivity(), mResources);
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.imageSliderHome);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
            mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();         

    }
 }

@Override
    public void onResume() { 
        super.onResume();

        swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (currentPage == mCustomPagerAdapter.getCount()) {
                            currentPage = 0;
                        }
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000, 5000);
    }



    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        swipeTimer.cancel();
    }
```

pager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_bg1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

logcat:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error
>   inflating class at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) at
>   foto.studio.CustomPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomPagerAdapter.java:38)
>   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837) at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1053) at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:555)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:506)
>   at foto.studio.HomeActivity$7$1.run(HomeActivity.java:146) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) ... 22
>   more Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683) at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
>   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3436) at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:133) at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:123) ... 25 more

Comment: `android:src="@drawable/splash_bg1"  ` is that valid reference?

Comment: I'm sure you get OutOfMemory exception. Post the full stacktrace here.

Comment: @metalurgus - sorry, I forgot earlier to post the whole stacktrace, please see my updated answer.

Comment: @IoaneSharvadze - shi***, it was in use earlier, but not for this slide, but the file is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `Runnable` and `Handler` to replace `Timer`. And show your logcat
And try [thiss method](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for scale bitmap

Comment: Thanks, please se the whole stacktrace (updated answer).

Comment: no problem. when i reading your post first time it haven't logcat :D

Answer (score 0):

As I expected, you get the OutOfMemory exception by loading too large/too many images.

> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.

To avoid it, read [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and [this one](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html), and don't forget to [recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()) images after using them. Also put the images into `drawable-nodpi` resource dir.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, so far it seems resampling helps, but it is hard to reproduce the error. Question: If I am planning to run my app on devices 4.0+, do I need "recycle()" still? The docs say it is meant for 2.3.3 and lover.

Comment: @EdmondTamas looks like this should be the last thing you should try if the others don't help...